# stored procedure even after null value saves the data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, optional-parameters

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STL_ADDNEWROLE](@ROLENAME VARCHAR(100), @STATUS BIT)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF(@ROLENAME IS NULL OR @STATUS IS NULL)
    BEGIN
       RETURN 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       IF EXISTS (SELECT [RoleName], [Status] FROM ST_Roles 
                  WHERE [RoleName] = @ROLENAME)
       BEGIN
          RETURN 0
       END
       ELSE IF(@ROLENAME IS NOT NULL)
       BEGIN
          INSERT INTO ST_Roles ([RoleName], [Status]) VALUES(@ROLENAME, @STATUS)
          RETURN 1
       END
    END
END
```

The above is my stored proc. When NULL values are passed it should return 0. Even when 1 value is passed and another value is not passed it should return 0 instead of inserting the record.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? at the moment it returns 0 if either are null, what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: what's the problem? Try to put default values for parameters.

Comment: On my computer this behaves the way you are describing. Maybe I'm not understanding the question? When either value is `null` it returns `0` and if the `RoleName` already exists it also returns `0`. It returns `1` when the `RoleName` is non-null and the `Status` is non-null and the `RoleName` does not already exist. How is this different from what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: when i enter rolename empty or null it is saving the data, instead i want it to return 0.

Comment: Try adding default values and/or check if @rolename is empty string. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you describe your problem, I'll just guess. I suppose the problem is in default parameters. Maybe you just don't pass parameters or you pass empty string, so try this way

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STL_ADDNEWROLE](
               @ROLENAME VARCHAR(100) = NULL, 
                @STATUS BIT = NULL)
        AS
        BEGIN   
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            IF(ISNULL(@ROLENAME, '') = '' OR @STATUS IS NULL)
                BEGIN
                    RETURN 0
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF EXISTS (SELECT [RoleName],[Status] from ST_Roles where  [RoleName] = @ROLENAME)
                        BEGIN
                            RETURN 0
                        END
                    ELSE IF(@ROLENAME IS NOT NULL)
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO ST_Roles ([RoleName],[Status]) VALUES(@ROLENAME,@STATUS)
                            RETURN 1
                        END
                END


        END
```

Comment: it working fine now. can you tell me is it mandatory to assign values as you did..?

Comment: Only if you have optional parameters. Check links for more info

Comment: http://blog.tech-cats.com/2008/01/using-optional-parameters-in-sql-server.html
http://geekswithblogs.net/whiletrue/archive/2009/02/28/optional-parameters-in-sql-stored-procedures.aspx